# Possible alternative expression for single variable limits

Tags: calculus, limits

All I wish to know is if it is possible to write $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} f(a\pm h)=L$, where you break the right hand side up into two cases $a+h$ and $a-h$ such that there is one case that is equal to the right limit and one case that is equal to the left limit.

To me, this intuitively makes a lot of sense but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: I don’t think you need the $\pm$; the limit captures the idea of approaching from different directions already

Comment: Your statement is correct if $f$ is both continuous and defined in the neighbourhood of $a$, as you can pass the limit inside the brackets (and thus if $L=f(a)$)

Comment: I think you're right about the $\pm$ being redundant because in fact the right hand expression captures both $h$ approaching $0$ from the left and right, thus being able to both take on very small positive and negative values. However, why should this only hold when $f$ is continuous. I mean you do not have to be able to directly substitute to be able to evaluate limits.

Comment: I’m not saying it *only* holds when $f$ is continuous, I’m just commenting that it does hold. If I knew any more, any more rigorously, I’d have posted an answer. This is an interesting question, as the answer morally should just be: “Yes!” But maths is full of strange counter examples

Comment: All right, now I understand your comment a lot better. Though not a full answer indeed it is still of value to me to know that the equation proposed in the question above is guaranteed to not be rubbish given a function that is continuous at $a$. The equation also holds for all of the examples I have tried, but as you have pointed out, one might at some point be surprised by something previously unknown